# Count number of options in selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

how to count number of options in dropdown using selectize.js?

`$('#MyDrop option').length;`

`$('#MyDrop option').size();`

Above ones are not working with selectize !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Selecize API, you can get options with this method:

```
options = $('#my_select_widget')[0].selectize.options;
```

Then loop through the object to count them:

```
var cnt = 0;
for(k in options){
    cnt++;
}
console.log(cnt);
```

Answer (score 9):

Get all options of selectize

`let options = $('#selectElem')[0].selectize.options;`

Get all keys of object

```
let count = Object.keys(options);
console.log(count.length);
```

Comment: this solution is more elegant